# How do I recover from a botched histedit in mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, backup, restore

I botched a histedit, and I'd like my original changesets back:

```
$ hg histedit
3 files updated, 0 files merged, 1 files removed, 0 files unresolved
saved backup bundle to /home/jla/solar_capture/.hg/strip-backup/ca681926dad2-a0fffac7-backup.hg
```

There appears to be a backup bundle, how do I make it as if I'd done

```
$ hg histedit --keep
```

like I intended to....

Answer (score 1):

```
hg unbundle /home/jla/solar_capture/.hg/strip-backup/ca681926dad2-a0fffac7-backup.hg
```