# Undo a bad histedit in Mercurial, using evolve

Tags: version-control, mercurial

Suppose I run `hg histedit`, make some changes, and commit. I then realize I made a mistake. How can I discard the new revision and return the repository to its state prior to the histedit?

I.e., does Mercurial have a safety-net analogous to `git reset --hard $BRANCH@{1}`?

(I'm also using the Evolve extension).

Comment: It's a bit trickier in Mercurial because the stripped changesets are stored in another format (as a bundle), but Mercurial does normally save any stripped changesets. When you did the history edit, Mercurial told you where it saved them.

Comment: Following on what @torek said, the solution to this other question should be quite similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47274499/undo-an-accidental-hg-strip  If you are not sure which bundle it was, you can look inside a bundle first I think with `hg incoming` from the bundle file. Also you can just sort them by timestamp.

Comment: I don't think that's right. histedit doesn't appear to strip changesets. They're all still visible when I run `hg log -G --hidden`. Essentially I just want to be able to hide the bad rev and unhide the previous rev and move the tip back to where it was.

Comment: It sounds like you have the Evolve extension turned on. This changes everything! (Unfortunately, I've never used it and don't know what the next step would be.)

Comment: Oh, yes, I do. I enabled it for `hg prune` without realizing it would change the behavior of other commands. Sorry, if I'd known I would have been sure to mention it.

Comment: The theory behind evolve is that instead of *removing* old commits in favor of new and improved ones, Mercurial can simply store both the old and new histories, with the old history marked "outdated" and the new one marked "use this instead". I don't know what *commands* will recover, but the *theory* is obvious: you just mark the replacement commits outdated with even-newer commits that match the original commits.

Comment: You should be able to see the old rewritten commits in "hg log --hidden". You can then use "hg touch" to revive them. You'll likely also need to prune the incorrect rewritten changes after reviving the old changes you want back.

Comment: With evolve enabled, the original changes are marked as obsolete and skipped by operations like "hg log" as hidden. As @ngoldbaum said,"hg log --hidden" will show them. The other option is "hg obsolete <revision>". That will parse the obsolescence markers and show you which changes e.g. have been rewritten into which newer changes. You can then discover the details using normal tools by adding "--hidden".

Comment: Sorry, that should have been "hg obslog".

Comment: If you found the head of the branch before the histedit (e.g. with `hg log --hidden` or `hg obslog <revision>` or TortoiseHg configured to show predecessors), you can go back to this state using `hg rewind --to <old head of branch>`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I recover from a botched histedit in mercurial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43742808/how-do-i-recover-from-a-botched-histedit-in-mercurial)